# How to model JSON array as protobuf definition

Tags: arrays, json, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am writing a new service in golang using protobuf. I want to model the following Request JSON in the .proto file.

```
[
   {
    "var": ["myVariable1","myVariable2"], 
    "key1": 123123,
    "key2": 1122,
    "key3": "abcd-0101"
   },
  { 
    "var": ["myVariable1"], 
    "key1": 123124,
    "key2": 1123,
    "key3": "abcd-0102"
  },
]
```

There are two problems currently :

- The keys in each array element are not known beforehand, hence I cannot create a message in .proto file and make it repeated. I need to keep it map
- I am unable to model a json which is just an array with no key. Everytime i do this, following error is shown : failed to decode request: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value

Following is my .proto file :

```
syntax = "proto3";

package pb;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";

service Transmitter {
  rpc GetVariables(GetVariablesRequest) returns (GetVariablesResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
                post: "/api/v1/{Service}/getVars"
                body: "*"
            };
  };
}


message GetVariablesRequest {
  string Service = 1;
  repeated GetVarInput in = 2;
}

message GetVariablesResponse {
  string msg = 1;
}

message GetVarInput {
  map<string,string> Input = 2;
}
```

I have tried with bytes instead of repeated GetVarInput, but it always comes empty. Also tried body:  "*" and body : "in"

Please provide some pointers.

Comment: Cant you just give the array some placeholder name in your json blob? e.g. `{ "data" : [ {...}, {...} ] }`

Answer (score 3):

You can write a message for your json like this:

```
message RequestMessage {
   string var = 0;
   double key1 = 1;
   double key2 = 2;
   string key3 = 3;
}
```

Further, you can create another message which contains an array of `RequestMessage`

```
message Request {
   repeated RequestMessage request = 0;
}
```

Comment: Only changes in above is - zero or negative is not allowed in proto3. so start  column with 1 .this worked for me thanks

Comment: I think the Request will map to json object instead of array. It would be {"request":[]}. How to map directly to an array?

Answer (score 1):

```
service UserService {
  rpc GetUsers(GetUsersRequest) returns (Users) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get : "/users"
    };
  };

  rpc GetUser(GetUserRequest) returns (User) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get : "/users/{user_id}"
    };
  };
}

message User {
  string id = 1;
  string display_name = 2;
  string icon_image_path = 3;
  string background_image_path = 4;
  string profile = 5;
  string email = 6;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp created_at = 8;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp updated_at = 9;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp deleted_at = 10;
}

message Users {
  repeated User user = 1;
}

message GetUsersRequest {}
message GetUserRequest { string user_id = 1; }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is usage of `Any` message in your .proto file. In this case you could have a repeated map with any GO types you need. But this approach is a bit overhead as it gives you a flexibility using strongly typed programming language. Here's an example:

```
message Any {
    string type = 1;
    bytes value = 2;
}
```

and in your GO code:

```
func GetRPCAnyValue(value interface{}) *pb.Any {
    bValue, type_val, _ := MarshlizeValue(value)
    return &pb.Any{
        Type: type_val,
        Value: bValue,
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer by Satyam Zode seems like the most reasonable one.

In your original question, you are trying to keep all the flexibility and dynamic nature of JSON, and in that case trying to convert it into protobuf makes little sense. You could just have a string field that contains the json.

However, protobuf does handle future changes to `RequestMessage` contents quite well, so you do not have to know the final set of fields yet. Just follow [Updating a Message Type](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#updating) to keep them compatible between different .proto file versions.